# Redirecionamento dinâmico com Switch Case PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Estou apanhando e não sei porque, pois é a primeira vez que tento fazer algo parecido, tenho um menu assim:

```
 <div id="collapseUtilities" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingUtilities" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
      <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
        <h6 class="collapse-header">Clientes:</h6>
        <a class="collapse-item" href="?page=cadastro_cliente">Cadastrar</a>
        <a class="collapse-item" href="">Editar</a>
        <a class="collapse-item" href="">Listar</a>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Como pode ver ele redireciona para uma page, lá embaixo eu tenho

```
  <?php switch($_GET['page']){

        case 'home': include 'home.php';
        case 'cadastro_cliente': include 'cadastro_cliente.php';
        case 'categorias': include 'categorias.php';

      } ?>
```

O que acontece é que se eu entro na página home.php ele lista embaixo a página cadastro_cliente e categorias, se eu entro no cadastro_cliente ele abre categorias logo embaixo, o que eu preciso fazer para abrir somente a página do case?

Abraço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja que o erro inicial está na omissão da declaração `break`. Veja o que diz o manual do PHP sobre isso:

> É importante entender como a declaração switch é executada a fim de
>   evitar enganos. A declação switch executa linha por linha (na verdade,
>   declaração por declaração). No início nenhum código é executado.
>   Somente quando uma declaração case é encontrada com um valores
>   correspondente ao valor da expressão do switch, o PHP começará a
>   executar a declaração. O PHP continuará a executar a declaração até o
>   fim do bloco switch, ou até a primeira declaração break encontrada. Se
>   não for escrita uma declaração break ao final da lista de declarações
>   do case, o PHP continuará executando as declarações dos próximos
>   cases.

[Fonte: Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.switch.php)

Sobre o código, é importante tratar a requisição e definir a "home" como página padrão, se nenhum valor for passado e no `switch`, também realizar um tratamento. Definir um `case default`, um padrão que corresponde a tudo que não foi correspondido pelos outros cases. Um exemplo no seu caso, uma pagina de erro 404.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $requisicao = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $requisicao = 'home';
}

switch($requisicao) {
    case "home":
        include(__DIR__."/home.php");
        break;
    case "cadastro_cliente": 
        include(__DIR__."/cadastro_cliente.php");
        break;
    case "categorias": 
        include(__DIR__."/categorias.php");
        break;
    default:
      include(__DIR__."/404.php");
}
```

A nível de informação e curiosidade, vale a pena falar aqui que este é o **básico** sobre o Padrão de Projeto Front Controller.

Answer (score 0):

No `switch`, é necessário terminar cada bloco `case` com um `break`. Caso contrário, o PHP vai continuar executando as declarações seguintes. Ficaria desse jeito:

```
 <?php switch($_GET['page']){

        case 'home': 
            include 'home.php';
            break;
        case 'cadastro_cliente': 
            include 'cadastro_cliente.php';
            break;
        case 'categorias': 
            include 'categorias.php'
            break;
  } ?>
```

Comment: Nem sempre "é necessário" . Tem muitas situações em que é desejável o efeito cascata. Obviamente não é o caso do autor, mas tem que tomar cuidado pra não generalizar.